# How to identify using xmlslurper in groovy, whether a node exists in my xml?

Tags: xml, groovy

I have this xml, I want to check the existence of `price` node if present then do set of actions else move on.

```
<game>
 <genre>
  <action>...</action>
  <racing>...</racing>
 <price>
  ..
  ..
  </price>
</genre>
</game>
```

How can I achieve this in groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I got the answer, this works fine for me.

xml is the GPathResult object that has the xml in it.

```
xml.children().find {it.name()=="price"}
```

//will return true if `price` exists